# IF MATCH multiple criteria

Tags: if-statement, excel-formula, match

[image: Table 1]

**Table 1**

```
|    | 1 Jan 2018 | 2 Jan 2018 | 3 Jan 2018 | 4 Jan 2018 | 5 Jan 2018 |
|----|------------|------------|------------|------------|------------|
| A1 |            |            |            |            |            |
| A2 |            |            |            |            |            |
| A3 |            |            |            |            |            |
| A4 |            |            |            |            |            |
| A5 |            |            |            |            |            |
| A6 |            |            |            |            |            |
```

[image]
**Table 2**

```
|----|----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
| A1 | 3-Jan-18 | 10-Jan-18 | 17-Jan-18 | 24-Jan-18 | 31-Jan-18 |
| A2 | 3-Jan-18 | 10-Jan-18 | 17-Jan-18 | 24-Jan-18 | 31-Jan-18 |
| A3 | 3-Jan-18 | 10-Jan-18 | 17-Jan-18 | 24-Jan-18 | 31-Jan-18 |
| A4 | 3-Jan-18 | 6-Jan-18  | 10-Jan-18 | 13-Jan-18 | 17-Jan-18 |
| A5 | 3-Jan-18 | 10-Jan-18 | 17-Jan-18 | 24-Jan-18 | 31-Jan-18 |
| A6 | 3-Jan-18 | 10-Jan-18 | 17-Jan-18 | 24-Jan-18 | 31-Jan-18 |
```

**IF MATCH**

```
=IF(MATCH(A2,$A$27:$A$54,0) & MATCH(C1,$B$27:$S$54,0),"1","")
```

- Getting #N/A error out of it
- Trying to get apply formula onto the cells in Table 1 to lookup values in Table 2
- If it matches, output is 1, else 0

Table & Image above to clearly illustrate & experiment out.
Thanks in advance (:

**Applied formula & Output**
[image: Applied Formula]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, `MATCH()` returns a number that represents the position of a found match so your formula says `IF(1 & 1,"1","")` for your first potential match, there is no logical here.

The first ammendment would be to force a True / False output: `=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(MATCH()),ISNUMBER(MATCH())),"1","")`

You still have the issue that the second match is referencing the entire range of resuts though, you really want this to only look through the row that meets the first criteria, for this we will use an array formula to build the array you want to use:

***EDIT: You can't buld an array from Match as it returns a single integer:***

`=LARGE(IF(B$1=IF($A2=$A$27:$A$54,$B$27:$S$54),1,0),1)`

**This is an array formula, while still in the formula bar hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>**

The Inner `IF()` statemnet is building an array of each row, providing values where column A matches and FALSE where it doesn't. The outter `IF()` statement is then evaluating 0 or 1 whether it finds the date in that new array...

I have wrapped this in a `LARGE()` to return the first largest number so if a single match is found it will return that 1. If you want the blank you can wrap the whole thing in another `IF()` statement; `IF([formula]=0,"",1)`

Comment: Thanks for explaining & I understand your answer, I did press Ctrl+Shift+Enter as well, but my out comparing with 3rd Jan is as blank as non-matching dates...

Comment: Okay, I'll mock up your data and take a look, I wrote this off the top of my head...

Comment: @Tyler Apologies, it was a clear rush job I wasn't thinking straight as you cannot use Match to build an array. I have edited the answer now showing how to use the if statment to produce your desired result...

Comment: I applied this from what you explain instead. {=IF(LARGE(IF(D$1=IF($A2=$A$27:$A$54,$B$27:$S$54),1,),1)=0,"",1)}
It works, and is surely saving me plenty of time from now on. Thanks a lot (: